# entry-overview superslow after update?

Tags: mysql, timeout

we have a little problem with craft after updating to the new version.
the entry-overview (foo.com/craft-admin/entries/) seems to load much slower than before when I click an entry (up to 10 seconds)
problem part 2: we just created about 100 sections, which makes the system complete unusable, as we run into timeouts by clicking certain entries. 
any idea how to deal with this?

Answer (score 3):

okay, guess I got it.
as soon as I kick the Preparse Field-plugin, everything works smooth. but i guess it's not the plugin that causes the trouble, it's the way craft is writing its logs for deprecated code?

another solution: RTFM..
in Preparse Field-plugin: activate "Disable all Preparse field columns on all element indices".

Comment: Yeah, update the preparse plugin to get rid of the deprecated messages, and disable the element indices thing, that will slow things down if you have alot of entries.